# Clarification of Self-Learner badge

Tags: feature-request, badges

I was just reading through the badges and noticed that the short description of the "[Self-Learner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner)" badge was a bit too ambiguous.

It currently reads:

> Answer your own question with score of 3 or more

which makes me think the question has to have a score of 3 or more, not the answer.

I believe it would make more sense as:

> Answer your own question, achieving a score of 3 or more

or something along those lines.

Comment: No, the answer needs to have a score of 3 or more. See the [central badges FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for) as well.

Comment: I know that, I'm talking about improving the short description. (To remove the need to read the full description to understand the tag)

Comment: I think so too. The badge does make it sound a bit like you have to answer your own question that has a score of 3 or more. Could be improved.

Comment: Uber-meta dupes: [Editing the "Self-Learner" Badge Description](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/181111) and [Clarify the "self-learner" badge description](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/101020)

Comment: Shoot, I didn't find those when I looked for duplicates XD

Comment: I should delete this right? It's just that the other questions aren't getting much attention.

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda Don't delete it, those are on Meta Stack Exchange, not Meta Stack Overflow, this question technically can't be marked as duplicate.

Comment: True, I'll leave it for now.

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda I'd suggest posting your suggestion as an answer and wait for others to follow along with their own. I will try thinking of one now.

Comment: It seems you are answering and asking for the same thing on MSE(Meta StackExchange) and MSO(Meta Stackoverflow) respectively. Got that from the comment of Martijn

Comment: This is one of those cases where the programming language creeps in the user facing messages: if (q.userid = a.userid && a.score >= 3) then awardbadge("self-learned);

Comment: @Braiam MissingQuoteDelimiterError on line 1 @ "self-learned

Comment: In your proposed rewording, I still see some ambiguity. I would add a comma between "question" and "achieving". Or maybe instead of "achieving", put "and achieve".

Comment: @TiiJ7 Yeah, I thought there should be a comma there. Just to be sure though, if we wait and see if your comment gets a few upvotes, I'll change it.

Answer (score 6):

> Any agreement out there?

Yes, I do agree that the badge's description could be a lot more clearer than the current one.

Now, here are new description ideas I have come up with:

> Post an answer with a score of 3 or more on your own question

OR (less favorable)

> Score of 3 or more on an answer to your own question

Answer (score 4):

> Post an Answer, that gets a score of 3 or more, on one of your own questions

Seems to explain which post needs what score, right?

Comment: It's a bit long winded but yes it works.

Comment: I think the existing description doesn't work *because* it is too succinct.

Comment: Neither of the commas should be there and you can remove "own"

Answer (score -13):

"Score 3 or more by answering your own question."